# Unexpected behavior of \g@addto@macro in class definition

Tags: macros, expansion, key-value

I am implementing a new class for a journal.

Withi this class, I defined the command to insert the authors of an article.
I anticipate that everything works perfectly in the basic form, that is, if the author name is inserted in this way:

```
\author[1]{Federico Tramarin}
```

where the index ([1]) is only for linking with the affiliation, and it is working correctly, so we shouldn't bother about that.

For editorial reasons, I have been asked to ask authors to also insert the abbreviated form of their names. Example: John Smith and J. Smith.

To accommodate for this, I created a key-value definition, in order to allow to insert the author in this way:

```
\author[1]{name=Federico,surname=Tramarin,abbreviation=F. Tramarin}
```

The keys are defined in this simple way:

```
\def\@tmpauthname{}
\define@key{authornames}{name}{%
    \def\@author@name{#1}}
\define@key{authornames}{surname}{%
    \def\@author@surname{#1}}
  \define@key{authornames}{abbreviation}{%
    \def\@authorshortname{#1}}
```

And then I modified the existing macro to

- use the second parameter to set the keys' values
- create a temporary string for the full author name
- use it in place of the secon parameter

For your information, the macro essentially defines two macros:

1. `\@AIauthors` - to create the final classical string to be typesetted after the title, with names and superscripts containing affiliation markers, etc.
2. `\@AIauthorsNames` - to create a simpler string with only the full names separated by a ';'.

These two macros are then called when typesetting the title page with `\maketitle`.

I put here the code I am using. Please note that the code below is almost identical to the working one (the one that allow to only insert a single argument with the name), since every time you see `\@tmpauthname` the original (and working) code contained a `#2`.

```
\newcounter{auth}
\def\@@author[#1]#2{%
    \setkeys{authornames}{#2}%
    \gdef\@tmpauthname{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}%
    \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 1-> auth:\@tmpauthname}
    \g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \refstepcounter{auth}% increment by 1
    \newif\ifnotyetprocessed% this if is needed to check if this author has already been counted for corresponding
    \notyetprocessedtrue
    \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 2-> auth:\@tmpauthname}
    \authorsep\@tmpauthname\unskip\textsuperscript{%
        \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{%
            %\typeout{Debug - @@author macro -> auth:\theauth\ affmark:\@@affmark - author:#1}
            \edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{affn?}{\AIrefMark{\@@affmark}}}%
            \unskip\sep\affnum%
            \ifnotyetprocessed%
                \NewAIaffLabel{auth-\theauth}{+}%
            \fi%
            \edef\cormark{\@ifundefined{X@cor-\theauth}{}{%
                \if@showcorr
                    {,\AIrefMark{cor-\theauth}}%
                \else
                    {}%
                \fi}}%
            %           \unskip\sep\cormark\let\sep=,% this line was wrong, since it will add a extra comma in case of multiple affiliations
            \unskip\cormark\let\sep=,% now the issue is for the corresponding author with multiple affiliations
            \ifx\cormark\@empty%
            \else
                \ifnotyetprocessed% if the author is corresponding and is the first time we are here
                    \g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{\@tmpauthname}% add the author name to the output
                    \notyetprocessedfalse %if it is a subsequent round, do nothing
                \fi
            \fi
            }%
        }%
    \gdef\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\sep\@empty%
    }
    \ifx\@AIauthorsNames\@empty
        \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 3-> auth:\@tmpauthname}
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{\@tmpauthname}%
        \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 3-> AIauth:\@AIauthorsNames}
    \else
        \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 4-> auth:\@tmpauthname}
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{;\space\@tmpauthname}%
        \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 4-> AIauth:\@AIauthorsNames}
    \fi
}
```

The issue is that, after this modification, that I thought was trivial, I obtain a string with only the last name repeated *n* times (with *n* the number of authors).

As you can see I have inserted some \typeout to have a very basic debug to see what is happening.

What I saw in the log is this:

- There is a first scan of the macro, where `\@tmpauthname` contains the name for the current author, but that skip all the parts inside the `\g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{%`. In practice, if you look at the number in the debug message, I see the numbers 1 and 3 or 4.
- A second scan of the macro (I see the number 2 in the debug) that execute the `\g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{%` but with the side effect that this time it is executed using only the last value saved in `\@tmpauthname`.

I have tried everything in my knowledge, but I wasn't able to solve my problem.
What I understood (i hope correctly) is that the `\@AIauthors` is evaluated later because it is needed only when I ask for the title page, and hence latex expand that part only when it needs it. Unfortunately, this happens only ofter all the authors have been specified, and when it expands the value of `\@tmpauthname`, the latter contains only the last value. This clearly doesn't happen when the classic `#2` argument was considered.

In my mind, I would need a way to tell LaTeX to evaluate immediately everything, after every new author is inserted, but I don't know 1) how to achieve this, 2) is it is the right solution.

I am aasking for your help to solve this issue, which is driving me crazy and asking already a whole day of attempts (this is obviously due to my ignorance in macro definition).

Thank you very much for any help you may give me.

Best regards
Federico

Comment: `\ExpandArgs{No}\g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{\@tmpauthname}` should work (in a current LaTeX. But as you didn't provide a small, full example it is untested.

Comment: Maybe `\tmpauthname` has to be expanded even more than once, because it is defined using `\gdef\@tmpauthname{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}` and therefore using other macros, that may be only temporary valid.

Comment: @cabohah right, yes, then more expansions are needed.

Comment: Don't do `\newif` inside of your code, place it once outside your function, set the conditional to false inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When asking a question where bug-tracking and modifying code plays a rôle always provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE)/minimal complete and verifiable example (MCVE) so that one can test whether changes to the code really solve the problem!*

*If you don't do this, then people willing to help are doomed to **guessing** that their attempts/modifications might probably solve the problem, which is not actually an efficient problem-solving-strategy.*

This time I will do some guesswork.

But I don't feel all too well while doing that.

---

Due to usage of `\g@addto@macro` I assume that it is about LaTeX 2ε.

You say:

> I put here the code I am using. Please note that the code below is almost identical to the working one (the one that allow to only insert a single argument with the name), since every time you see `\@tmpauthname` the original (and working) code contained a `#2`.

How about not replacing `#2` by `\@tmpauthname` but "outsourcing" those portions of code where `#2` is to hold what it used to hold in the working code into a persisting helper macro and calling that persisting helper macro while providing as its 2<sup>nd</sup> argument those tokens that in the working macro used to form `#2`?

Probably s.th. like this—untested as you did not provide a minimal reproducible/complete and verifiable example where things can be tested!!!:

```latex
\newcounter{auth}
\newif\ifnotyetprocessed

\def\@@author[#1]#2{%
  \setkeys{authornames}{#2}%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begingroup
  % In LaTeX 2e \toks@ is a token register.
  \toks@{\endgroup\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{#1}}%
  \protected@edef\TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO{%
    \the\toks@{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}%
  }%
  \TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %% Alternatively, if \expanded and \unexpanded are available:
  %\begingroup
  %\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  %\expanded{%
  %  \endgroup
  %  \unexpanded{\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{#1}}{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}%
  %}%
}%
\long\def\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO#1#2{%
  \g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \refstepcounter{auth}% increment by 1
    \notyetprocessedtrue
    \authorsep#2\unskip
    \textsuperscript{%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{%
        \edef\affnum{%
          \@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{affn?}{\AIrefMark{\@@affmark}}%
        }%
        \unskip\sep\affnum
        \ifnotyetprocessed
          \NewAIaffLabel{auth-\theauth}{+}%
        \fi
        \edef\cormark{%
          \@ifundefined{X@cor-\theauth}{}{%
            \if@showcorr
              {,\AIrefMark{cor-\theauth}}%
            \else
              {}%
            \fi
          }%
        }%
        \unskip\cormark
        \let\sep=,% now the issue is for the corresponding author with multiple affiliations
        \ifx\cormark\@empty
        \else
          \ifnotyetprocessed % if the author is corresponding and is the first time we are here
            \g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{#2}% add the author name to the output
            \notyetprocessedfalse % if it is a subsequent round, do nothing
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    }%
    \gdef\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\sep\@empty
  }%%
  \ifx\@AIauthorsNames\@empty
    \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{#2}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{;\space#2}%
  \fi
}%
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent trying to debug my code. Please forgive me for not having provided a MWE, I thought it was too much code but tomorrow I will try to upload it.

Your code works!

Just a couple of quick question: 

1) why in the call of \PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{#1} you use only 1 argument, whereas the macro requires 2? the code works, but I am not able to understand why!

2) why closing the group just after the `\toks@}` and inside the argument, I am not able to understand, as I don't understand the definition of after the call to \PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO

Thank you  again

Comment: @trama You're welcome.  Ad 1) I don't use `\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{#1}` with only one argument when carrying out the call to `\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO`. I use that while constructing the call to `\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO`. The second argument of `\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO` gets appended to what is constructed so far before letting TeX carry out/expand `\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO`.  ;-)

Comment: @trama Ad 2) `\toks@{...}` is an assignment and means that `...` is to form the content of the token register `\toks@`. So `\endgroup` is one of the tokens that are to form the content of the token-register `\toks@`. You get `\endgroup` with the rest of the content of the token-register when having the command `\the\toks@` "spit out" the content of the token-register `\toks@`.  Getting that token in turn doesn't necessarily mean carrying it out. As ...

Comment: @trama  ...  As `\the\toks@` in turn is done while `\protected@edef` takes place, you get that token plus the rest of the content of the token-register `\the\toks@` as a component of the <replacement text> of the macro `\TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO`. ;-)

Comment: @trama `\toks@{\endgroup\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{#1}}`: This assignment makes the tokens `\endgroup\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{<tokens that form \@@author's argument #1>}` the content of the token register `\toks@`.

Comment: @trama `\protected@edef\TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO{\the\toks@{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}}`: This defines `\TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO` to expand to what at definition-time is the content of `\tok@`, without expanding that content further, trailed by total expansion of `{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}`. So `\TEMPORARYHELPERMACRO` expands to `\endgroup\PERSISTINGHELPERMACRO{<tokens that form \@@author's argument #1>}{<total expansion of \@author@name\space\@author@surname>}`.

Comment: @trama With `\edef`/`\protected@edef` tokens forming the <replacement text> of the definition are expanded. Exception: With tokens coming from expanding `\the<register>` further expansion is suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bothering with expansion you can simply use a key=value parser which doesn't store the values inside of macros, but instead forwards them as separate parameters to another macro.

This is done by `expkv-cs` (*disclaimer:* I'm the author) with the macro `\ekvcSplitAndForward`.

Note that I didn't change your code all that much, I only replaced `\@tmpauthname` with the correct contents forwarded as `#1` (and since we get the name as normal parameters we don't have to include any expansion control to achieve this here).

I made a few changes though:

- use `\NewDocumentCommand` as a front facing macro for `\author`.
- use `\NewDocumentCommand` to define `\@@author` protected.
- move `\newif` outside the function body.
- decouple the `\g@addto@macro` and the formatting of the author by using an auxiliary `\output@author` (this way the code looks much cleaner, and the performance should be considerably better).
- I removed some of your debugging messages
- I changed the `\g@addto@macro` to a `\gdef` for an empty `\@AIauthorsNames`
- I removed some unwanted spaces by adding `%` at some line ends.
- and lastly, I reformatted your code to fit my tastes (indentations by 2 spaces, no line of code longer than 80 characters (including comments) ...)

```
\RequirePackage{expkv-cs}

\NewDocumentCommand\author{O{} m}
  {\@author{#2}{#1}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\@author\@@author
  {
     name         = {}
    ,surname      = {}
    ,abbreviation = {}
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\@author
  {
    % abbreviation is such a long word... Let's define an abbreviated form.
    alias abbr = abbreviation
  }

\newcounter{auth}
% this if is needed to check if this author has already been counted for
% corresponding
\newif\ifnotyetprocessed
\NewDocumentCommand\@@author{m m m m}
  {%
    % #1: name
    % #2: surname
    % #3: abbreviation
    % #4: affiliations
    % handle mandatory keys (throw an error if they were omitted)
    \IfEmptyT{#1#2}
      {\PackageError{trama}{Authors must have names, please provide them.}{}}%
    \IfEmptyT{#3}
      {\PackageError{trama}{Missing name abbreviation.}{}}%
    \g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{\output@author{#1 #2}{#4}}%
    \ifx\@AIauthorsNames\@empty
      \gdef\@AIauthorsNames{#1 #2}%
      \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 3-> AIauth:\@AIauthorsNames}%
    \else
      \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{; #1 #2}%
      \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 4-> AIauth:\@AIauthorsNames}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\output@author[2]
  {%
    % #1: <name> <surname>
    % #2: affiliations
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \refstepcounter{auth}% increment by 1
    \notyetprocessedtrue
    \typeout{Debug - @@author macro 2-> auth:#1}%
    \authorsep#1\unskip\textsuperscript
      {%
        \@for\@@affmark:=#2\do
          {%
            %\typeout
            %  {%
            %    Debug - @@author macro -> auth:\theauth\ affmark:\@@affmark -
            %    author:#4
            %  }%
            \edef\affnum
              {\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{affn?}{\AIrefMark{\@@affmark}}}%
            \unskip\sep\affnum
            \ifnotyetprocessed
              \NewAIaffLabel{auth-\theauth}{+}%
            \fi
            \edef\cormark
              {%
                \@ifundefined{X@cor-\theauth}
                  {}%
                  {%
                    \if@showcorr
                      {,\AIrefMark{cor-\theauth}}%
                    \else
                      {}%
                    \fi
                  }%
              }%
            % this line was wrong, since it will add a extra comma in case of
            % multiple affiliations:
            %           \unskip\sep\cormark\let\sep=,%
            % now the issue is for the corresponding author with multiple
            % affiliations
            \unskip\cormark\let\sep=,%
            \ifx\cormark\@empty
            \else
              % if the author is corresponding and is the first time we are here
              \ifnotyetprocessed
                % add the author name to the output
                \g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{#1}%
                \notyetprocessedfalse %if it is a subsequent round, do nothing
              \fi
            \fi
          }%
      }%
    \gdef\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
    \global\let\sep\@empty
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution seems extremely neat, and I will try it tomorrow. The only thing is that it requires a further package to load, and another requirement I have been asked for is to keep the number of package dependencies to the least possible. However, given it is so neat, I would like to try it. Thanks

Comment: @trama you can drop `keyval` from the list of required packages... Though technically `expkv-cs` requires `expkv`, so you got an implicit dependency more. And the "no packages" requirement wasn't in your question :P Also, I just realised there's a bug `\g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{\@tmpauthname}` should use `#1` instead (or else we store a macro away that's gonna change definition to the next author).

Answer (score 0):

Just as un update, I created a working MWE, that is based on the help of @Ulrich Diez. I thank him for the suggestion that made the code working.

In the following days I would also try the solution by @Skillmon since I found it super neat (ok, in. my opinion).

Should someone of you ever notice some potential issues with my code, I would be happy to hear and revise it.

Thank you again

Federico

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter

\def\author{\@@author}
\def\@AIaffiliations{}
\def\@AIauthors{}
\def\@AIauthorsNames{}
\def\@AIauthorsNamesCitation{}

%some temporary variables for internal use
\let\authorsep\@empty
\let\sep\@empty
\let\@cormark\@empty
\def\CorrespondingAuthor{}
\def\@CorrespondingAuthorName{}

\def\@author@name{}
\def\@author@surname{}
\def\@authorshortname{}

\def\@tmpauthname{}

\define@key{authornames}{name}{%
    \def\@author@name{#1}}
\define@key{authornames}{surname}{%
\def\@author@surname{#1}}
\define@key{authornames}{abbreviation}{%
\def\@authorshortname{#1}}

\newif\ifnotyetprocessed

\def\@@author[#1]#2{%
    \setkeys{authornames}{#2}%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begingroup
    % In LaTeX 2e \toks@ is a token register.
    \toks@{\endgroup\processauthor{#1}}%
    \protected@edef\tmpauthname{%
        \the\toks@{\@author@name\space\@author@surname}{\@authorshortname}%
    }%
    \tmpauthname
}%

\newcounter{auth}
\long\def\processauthor#1#2#3{%
    \g@addto@macro\@AIauthors{%
        \def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \refstepcounter{auth}% increment by 1
        \notyetprocessedtrue
        \authorsep#2\unskip
        \textsuperscript{%
            \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{%
                \edef\affnum{%
                    \@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{affn?}{\AIrefMark{\@@affmark}}%
                }%
                \unskip\sep\affnum%
                \edef\cormark{%
                    \@ifundefined{X@cor-\theauth}{}{{}}%
                }%
                \unskip\cormark
                \let\sep=,%
                \ifx\cormark\@empty
                \else
                    \ifnotyetprocessed
                        \g@addto@macro\@CorrespondingAuthorName{#2}
                        \notyetprocessedfalse 
                    \fi
                \fi
            }%
        }%
        \gdef\authorsep{\unskip,\space}%
        \global\let\sep\@empty
    }%%
    \ifx\@AIauthorsNames\@empty
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{#2}%
    \else
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNames{;\space#2}%
    \fi
    \ifx\@AIauthorsNamesCitation\@empty
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNamesCitation{#3}%
    \else
        \g@addto@macro\@AIauthorsNamesCitation{;\space#3}%
    \fi
}%

\def\affiliation{\@@affiliation}
\newcounter{affn}
\renewcommand\theaffn{\arabic{affn}}
\long\def\@@affiliation[#1]#2{%
    \g@addto@macro\@AIaffiliations{%
        \def\baselinestretch{1}%
        \refstepcounter{affn}%
        \AIaffLabel{#1}
        {\upshape\textsuperscript{\theaffn}}\space#2\par\vspace{1pt}}%
}

\def\AIaffLabel#1{\@bsphack\protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\NewAIaffLabel{#1}{\@currentlabel}}\@esphack}
\def\NewAIaffLabel#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname X@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\AIrefMark#1{\@ifundefined{X@#1}{0}{\csname X@#1\endcsname}%
}

\def\CorrespondingAuthorNumber#1{\NewAIaffLabel{cor-#1}{$\ast$}}

\newcounter{cnote}
\def\CorrespondingAuthorEmail#1{\refstepcounter{cnote}%
    \AIaffLabel{#1}%
    \g@addto@macro\CorrespondingAuthor{%
        \@CorrespondingAuthorName, e-mail: #1}}

\def\@Citation{\@AIauthorsNamesCitation\space-\space\@title}

\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
        \begingroup
        \huge{\bfseries\@title}\par%
        \vskip15pt%
        \large{\bfseries\@AIauthors}\par%
        \vskip14pt%
        \itshape\small\@AIaffiliations\par%
        {\bfseries Corresponding Author:}\space\CorrespondingAuthor\par
        \vskip6pt%pt%
        {\bfseries Citation:}\space\@Citation\par
        \endgroup%%
    }
    
\makeatother

\title{Test}
\author[a1,a2]{name=Tom,surname=Smith,abbreviation=T. Smith}%
\author[a2,a3]{name=Jane,surname=Doe,abbreviation=J. Doe}%
\author[a3,a4]{name=Alfred,surname=Einstein,abbreviation=A. Einstein}%

\affiliation[a1]{First Affiliation}
\affiliation[a2]{Second Affiliation}
\affiliation[a3]{Another Affiliation}
\affiliation[a4]{Just another Affiliation}
\CorrespondingAuthorNumber{3}
\CorrespondingAuthorEmail{some@email.com}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```